# deferred.resolve() in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deferred, q

I need to intercept the change of ng-view and load a "loading div" overlay untill all new images are loaded.

I'm trying to suspend promises callbacks in my HttpInterceptor but I can't resolve my promise in a second time.

Here an example:

```
return function (promise) {
    globalForTest = $q.defer();

    return promise.then(function (response) {
        console.log('first', response);
        return globalForTest.promise;
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log('second', response);
        return response;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmvjh/

When I try to call globalForTest.resolve(value) nothing happens, neither an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works, but since your invoking `resolve` outside of angular lifecycle, you need to [explicitly call `$scope.$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q) to set things in motion. Otherwise callbacks won't be invoked.

[Link to fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmvjh/3/)