# Angular Promise ($q) is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use Angular with SignalR in my demo application. I am trying to use $q service to use promises. Don't know whats wrong in my code but its not working.

SERVICE

```
var boardConsole = $.connection.builtinboard;
var chat = angular.module('chat', []);
chat.factory('board', ['$q', '$timeout', function ($q, $timeout) {
var board = {};
board.startBoard = function (callback) {
    $.connection.hub.start(function () {
        if (angular.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback();
        }
    });
};
board.loadAllMessages = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    boardConsole.server.loadAllMessages().done(function (messages) {
        deferred.resolve(messages);
    }).fail(function () {
        deferred.reject(function () {
            //SHOW NOTHING FOUND 
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
return board;
} ]);
```

CONTROLLER

```
chat.controller('chatController', ['$scope', 'board', function ($scope, board) {
$scope.Messages = [];
board.startBoard(function () {
    board.loadAllMessages().then(function (messages) {
        alert('1');
        $scope.Messages = messages;
    });
});
} ]);
```

**its not working**

Comment: You have to call $rootScope.$apply() after you resolved/rejected promise, otherwise angular doesn't know that promise was resolved

Comment: `but its not working.` good sentence. Errors, logs, something, did you try  to debug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [deferred.resolve() in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426413/deferred-resolve-in-angularjs)

Comment: Try to add console.log under `deferred.resolve(messages);`

Comment: Jusio, why doesn't Angular know the promise has not been resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it in a `$timeout`. This will perform a safe `$apply` if necessary.

```
$timeout(function(){
    deferred.resolve(messages);
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. See http://plnkr.co/edit/nAmUkM0hF0hXACnIEJr0?p=preview

Comment: Try using `then` instead of `finally`.